# How to convert JSON array objects into list array | Swift 5

Tags: swift

I have the following JSON array that is decoded from a URL, currently I am able to parse the array to access invisible object, but how can I recreate a list array of only `trialid` from the JSON.
End result should look like: `[27, 33]`

**The following is the structure of the JSON array:**

```
[
  {
    "name": "mobile",
    "orderid": 1,
    "trialid": 27
  },
  {
    "name": "mobile",
    "orderid": 1,
    "trialid": 33
  }
]
```

**The following is the what I am currently trying - how can foreach be performed here to loop through each object:**

```
var structure = [testStructure]()

func fetch() {
        guard let url = URL(string: "test.com")
        else { return }
        
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.httpBody = "id=1".data(using: .utf8)
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, _, error in
            guard let data = data else { return }
            
            do {
                let nav  = try JSONDecoder().decode(structure, from: data)
                
              
                    
                
            }
            catch {
                print(error)
            }
            
        }.resume()
        
    }


 struct testStructure: Decodable {
    let name: String?
    let orderid: Int?
    let trialid: Int?
}
```

**UPDATE:**

After converting into a list array, I am doing the following afterwards to initiate view controllers from Storyboards

```
   case .success( let data):
        do {
            let nav = try JSONDecoder().decode([TestStructure].self, from: data)
            self.viewControllers = (nav.map(\.trialid)) { "\($0)" }.map {
                
                let selected = UIImage(named: "Tab4_Large")!
                let normal = UIImage(named: "Tab4_Large")!
                let controller = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: $0)
                controller.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
                controller.floatingTabItem = FloatingTabItem(selectedImage: selected, normalImage: normal)
                return controller
            }
            
        }
        
        catch {print(error)}
```

This is to overall build up a custom navigation bar

**Issue 1:**

> Unable to infer complex closure return type; add explicit type to
> disambiguate

**Issue 2:**

> Cannot call value of non-function type '[Int?]'

Comment: See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/48023537/6884584 . Your decoding should be `let nav = try JSONDecoder().decode([TestStructure].self, from: data)`. Also, object types should start with a capital letter (`struct TestStructure`). Would also recommend having a look over https://swift.org/documentation/api-design-guidelines/ to ensure some good practices ;).

Comment: @AlexIoja-Yang Please see my updated post, I appreciate the help

Comment: You already had the same topic some 12 hours ago.  Why don't you edit the last one instead of opening a new one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all please name structs and classes always with starting uppercase letter and declare the struct members non-optional if the API sends consistent data

```
struct TestStructure: Decodable {
    let name: String
    let orderid: Int
    let trialid: Int
}
```

Second of all the decoding line doesn't compile, you have to write

```
let nav = try JSONDecoder().decode([TestStructure].self, from: data)
```

To get an array of all `trialid` values just `map` it

```
let allTrialids = nav.map(\.trialid)
```

Update: Take the compiler's advice and ***add explicit type to disambiguate***

```
self.viewControllers = nav.map { test -> UIViewController in
    let selected = UIImage(named: "Tab4_Large")!
    let normal = UIImage(named: "Tab4_Large")!
    let controller = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: String(test.trialid))
    controller.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    controller.floatingTabItem = FloatingTabItem(selectedImage: selected, normalImage: normal)
    return controller
}
```

Comment: I appreciate the help  - can you please see my updated post, I am a bit confused how to use array list to initiate the view controllers. My original code that had the following static values worked with no issue `viewControllers = (1...4).map { "Tab\($0)" }.map {` .

Comment: I completely understand this question is a bit off topic from the original, but appreciate any guidance. Thank you

Comment: See the update. Actually you need only **one** `map`

Comment: I get the following error: `let controller = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: String(test.trialid))`

Comment: No exact matches in call to initializer

Comment: Your `trialId` is still optional, isn't it?

Comment: Yes that was the issue, thanks